# preg_replace match excluding string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

```
$string = ' prepending string ... "{something wrapped with " quotes } inside of braces}" appending string...';
$string .= '"{something "similar again{}}"';
```

I need to match slices wrapped by `'"{*}"'` in this string with preg_match and cannot find sollution.

It's easy for me to match one break sign like this: `'/([^"]+)/'`, but its not usefull for string of two signs.
For example this is not working: `'/"\{([^(\}")]+)\}"/'`.

Is possible to match all these slices wrapped by signs pairs in string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to use an ungreedy pattern here:

```
$pattern = '/"\{(.*)\}"/U';
```

It is unclear to me whether you need to verify that `"` or `{}` exist within the outer `"{*}"` construct in order for the match to take place.  If so, let me know and I will revise answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is just what i need. I did'nt know about ungreedy switch.